# Equalling the geometric average to the arithmetic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, systems-of-equations, average

I have a range of numbers numbers $n_i$, each with a different weight $w_i$ that sum up to 1. To keep things simple, let's take the case where we have three numbers with the following weights:

```
    n_i                       w_i
    ------------------------------
    100                       0.5
    30                        0.2
    20                        0.3
```

Their geometric average is $(100^{0.5})*(30^{0.2})*(20^{0.3})=48.4991$. The arithmetic average of the numbers is $100*0.5 + 30*0.2 + 20*0.3=62$, so it is larger than the geometric average.

How can I find a new set of normalized weights $w_i'$ that sum to 1 that can be used to find the arithmetic average of the numbers such that it is equal to the geometric average? In other words, I would like to find a new set $w_i'$ such that

$100*w_1' + 30*w_2' + 20*w_3' = (100^{0.5})*(30^{0.2})*(20^{0.3})$ given that $w_1'+w_2'+w_3'=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. You can see that by observing that the smallest $n$, $20$,  is less than the target (the geometric mean) and the largest $n$, $100$, is greater, so you can find a weighted average of just these two that does the job.

The algebra is easy: just solve
$$
20t + 100(1-t) = 48.4991
$$
for $t$; use $0$ for the weight of $30$.

This argument works for any input data.

There will in fact be lots of solutions when there are more than two numbers involved. The complete solution isn't that hard to write down. Since you have two linear equations for the three unknown weights (they sum to $1$ and they must produce the right weighted average) the solutions will form a family with one free parameter. You probably know enough algebra to work that out.

Comment: @BillyJean See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. Of course there are a range of trivial solutions if we do not assume the weights are nonzero. What about the case when we do assume that are all greater than zero?

Comment: Yeah, for three numbers it is easy enough -- but is it possible to generalize it?

Comment: @BillyJean Yes. For $2+k$ numbers there will be $k$ free parameters, since there are $2$ equations in $2+k$ unknowns. This is standard linear algebra, that you haven't quite gotten to yet in your studies. You can find some online tools by searching for _simultaneous equation solver_. I don't know whether any of them will help you with your particular problem. I note from your profile that you're a programmer. Many languages have linear algebra packages that might help.